# PHP class variables as public giving an error

Tags: php, class

I'm really new to php classes and now i have an error on my code. I have read some PHP documentations about classes and stuff, but something isn't just working correctly now.

Here's the code

```
public function change_salts($user_id) {
        global $mysqli_db;
        public $new_salt_one = "LOL"; //SaltyLogin::makesalt(60);
        private $new_salt_two = SaltyLogin::makesalt(60);
        mysqli_query($mysqli_db, "UPDATE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS)."` SET `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS_SALT_ONE)."`='".$new_salt_one."' WHERE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_USER_ID)."` = '".SaltyLogin::sanitize($user_id)."'");
        mysqli_query($mysqli_db, "UPDATE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS)."` SET `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS_SALT_TWO)."`='".$new_salt_two."' WHERE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_USER_ID)."` = '".SaltyLogin::sanitize($user_id)."'");
    }
```

Now this is the error I get all the time.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\xampp\htdocs\GitHub\Salty-login\functions.php on line 60
```

For full source code, have a look at [github](https://github.com/mirorauhala/Salty-login/tree/wip-2) and naturally branch wip-2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use encapsulation inside of the functions/methods, only in class declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare class variables in side of a function. You have to either move them out of the method or make them local to the function only:

**Option 1**

```
public $new_salt_one = "LOL"; 
private $new_salt_two = '';
public function change_salts($user_id) {
    global $mysqli_db;
    $this->new_salt_two = SaltyLogin::makesalt(60);
    mysqli_query($mysqli_db, "UPDATE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS)."` SET `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS_SALT_ONE)."`='".$this->new_salt_one."' WHERE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_USER_ID)."` = '".SaltyLogin::sanitize($user_id)."'");
    mysqli_query($mysqli_db, "UPDATE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS)."` SET `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_SALTS_SALT_TWO)."`='".$this->new_salt_two."' WHERE `".SaltyLogin::sanitize(SALTY_MYSQLI_TB_USER_ID)."` = '".SaltyLogin::sanitize($user_id)."'");
}
```

**Option 2**

```
$new_salt_one = "LOL"; 
$new_salt_two = SaltyLogin::makesalt(60);
```

Comment: plus class variables can't be initialized with expression results. constants only.